# Lightning - Context URL - Get get Id from URL

Tags: apex

We are using Lightning.

Context URL
https://stiyej--sdsd.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/ContentDocument/0690D00000sdsdRQAS

We want to get the conten id from the url in Apex. Is there any way we could get it ?

We are not using lightning component. Basically we are using data grid. So we want to know if it is possible directly in Apex to get the id from the context URL.

Comment: `0690D00000sdsdRQAS` this is the content document id, which you can get using `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()`. Can you please explain a bit more and what you have done so far ?

Comment: How are you using a data grid *without* using a Lightning component? In what context is your code exposed?